# Save file on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've created an editor in html, editor text was saved (or downloaded) in my browser downloads folder now, as the page is on tomcat I want it to save the file(editor text) in the server WEB-INF folder. On my search I found that I can only do this by JSP, how should I write the path in JSP such that the download is saved in WEB-INF? can I include it in my html page code below? if so how should be the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 7%;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor">
Blah blah blah
</div>


<script src="ace-builds-master/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script>
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/cobalt");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/gc");
</script>

<button type= "button" style="position: absolute; left: 10%; bottom: 2%;" id="execute" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Click to execute</button>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
function saveTextAsFile()
{
  var script = ace.edit("editor");
  var textToWrite = script.getValue() 
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'.c'});
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "my.c";

 var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
 downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  if (window.webkitURL != null)
  {
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  }
  else
  {
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current html/javascript editor runs on the client side (i.e web browser). JSP runs on the server side. Currently you are running a server locally. It looks like you are dynamically creating a link to your document:  `document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);`When a user clicks on the link the web browser will invoke a "file dialog" that has access to the local file system. The "file dialog" will not have access to the server file system (that is, if you move your deployment from the local host to a remote server).

So, if you are saying you will never run a remote server, then all you have to do is navigate with the web browser's file dialog to you WEB-INF location. I assume that you are trying something more?

If you instead want to send the "textFileAsBlob" to the server, you can do so with javascript. You would extend your javascript code to perform an ajax request (e.g. HTTP POST) to the server. The server would then need to inspect the request and then save the file to the server's file system (assuming that is what you are asking). If that is correct, you can use one of the many servlet file upload libraries. For example: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi

So if I am correct. You want to transfer the data from a client to a server. You need to replace the "link creation" with an ajax call to the server. Add a "file upload" processing to your server.

Hope that help :) Good luck.

Comment: Thank You really nice answer! Very well explained! will learn and use ajax.

Comment: I have one doubt, if I save it my path in my WEB-INF folder is there a way I could delete it automatically? or alteast open it, erase contents and then update with new info?

Comment: The WEB-INF typically is used to program artifacts (classes, libraries, internal config files). Most Content Management Systems (CMS) would store the data in a database (not the file system). If you are required to store on the file system, you can store outside of WEB-INF (anywhere the user account running your web app has access to). Updating a WEB-INF directory while the app is running creates all sorts of issues. Thus, I would avoid. Perhaps you should open a new question if really want an extended architectural discussion. Good Luck :)